# ¿Se puede hacer pruebas con datos de una consulta con PHPUnit?

Tags: php, pruebas-unitarias, phpunit

Tengo este código

```
<?php
  use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

  class PacienteTest extends TestCase {
    
    private $pac;

    public function setUp():void{
      $this->pac = new Paciente(0, 'Juan', 'Trejo Trejo', 'JUAN2328', '2022-06-11', 'Masculino', '9191118500', 't.fernandooo.11@gmail.com', 'hola', 1, 0, 1, 1);
    }
    /** @test **/
    public function testGetNombre(){
      $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Hospital");
      $this->pac->save($conexion);
      $name = $conexion->query("SELECT nom_persona FROM personas ORDER BY id_personas DESC LIMIT 1");
      $this->assertEquals($this->pac->getName(), $name);
    }
  }
?>
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar la prueba me dice que el `$name` es de tipo `Object` y no sé si se pueda en realidad comparar un dato de la bd como lo quiero hacer o las pruebas con PHPUnit son meramente con las clases y métodos sin incluir bd. ¿Es posible lo que intento hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto:

```
$conexion->query("SELECT nom_persona FROM personas ORDER BY id_personas DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Devuelve un objeto, puedes poner algo como esto:

```
$result = $conexion->query("SELECT nom_persona as nombre FROM personas ORDER BY id_personas DESC LIMIT 1");
$fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
$this->assertEquals($this->pac->getName(), $fila["nombre"]);
```

Comment: Ok, gracias, solo una cosa, la parte de la variable $result se igualaría al resultado de la consutla no? quedaría como $result = $conexion->query("SELECT nom_persona as nombre FROM personas ORDER BY id_personas DESC LIMIT 1"); o no? es que con $result-> me da error
---UPDATE- Probé con $result = y sí me funcionó, te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: Si se me pasó ese error !!!! Me alegro que te haya funcionado finalmente. Recuerda dejar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos